# Magento 2 - Success/Fail Messages Not Dislpaying

Tags: magento2, blocks, messages

None of my success/fail messages showing up.  I see in the debugger that the PHP code is setting the object just fine, it just isn't showing up on the web site.  No login failures.  No item added to cart.  Nothing.

I see that messages.phtml is being loaded in through the dev tools in Chrome. (Network/XHR)  It just doesn't seem that it is getting included in the template.

What might I be missing, or have mistakenly omitted in our custom theme?

Here is some experts from the source:

```
<div class="page messages"><div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                        "messages": {
                            "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>
```

Template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                        "messages": {
                            "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>
```

Layout:

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="page.main.title" template="html/title.phtml"/>
    <container name="page.messages" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme template was missing the binding for `cookieMessages` that was added in 2.0.8. Making this adjustment to the template will do the trick:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                        "messages": {
                            "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>
```